# Adjust font size of x-axis and y-axis labels in Seaborn Matplotlib PyQT5

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, seaborn

I want to adjust the font size of the x-Axis labels and y-labels.

```
    plt.style.use("dark_background")
    self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 2), dpi=120)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    self.figure.clear()

    fig = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': years, 'Buyer Count': buyerCount})

    for i in df.index:
        word = df.loc[i, "Buyer Count"]
        y = df.loc[i, "Buyer Count"]
        plt.annotate(f'{word:,.0f}', (i, y), ha="center", va="bottom", fontsize=8)

    sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Buyer Count', data=df).set(title="Buyers".format(year))
    self.customers_chart.addWidget(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.show()
```

[image: X-Label]
[image: Bar Plot in Question]

I have tried using

```
p = sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Buyer Count', data=df).set(title="Buyers".format(year))
p.set_xlabel("X-Axis", fontsize = 12)
p.set_ylabel("Y-Axis", fontsize = 12)
```

But an error arises:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'
```

Comment: Do you mean the axis labels, or the tick labels?

Comment: I realized that I am referring to the tick labels. I was confused what they were called. Been searching for 2 days now.

Comment: @DavidG Found the answer plus the list error answer by Z-Y.L below. Example: p.set_xticklabels(years, fontsize=4) to adjust the font size of the years overlapping. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Buyer Count', data=df)` returns a matplotlib `Axes`, while `sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Buyer Count', data=df).set(title="Buyers".format(year))` returns a list as the error told.

```py
p = sns.barplot(x='Year', y='Buyer Count', data=df)
p.set(title="Buyers".format(year))
p.set_xlabel("X-Axis", fontsize = 12)
p.set_ylabel("Y-Axis", fontsize = 12)
```

Don't call `.set` method directly, and refactor the code as above. This should not give any errors.

Comment: Okay! This is what I needed. I was confused what they were called. Apparently, I was referred to the "tick labels". I'll search how to adjust the tick labels from here. So, the .set() was one of the problems I didn't see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Found the answer plus the list error answer by @Z-Y.L. 

Example: 

p.set_xticklabels(years, fontsize=4) # to adjust the font size of the years overlapping.